# What are the highlights of GRUI?

Tags: reactjs, sencha-grui, grui

I need to use Tree Grid with grouping, sorting and filtering in my React project like Ext JS GRID, I found Sencha GRUI component and love it, What is the available top features in GRUI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- GRUI is perfect blend of the best of two different worlds. The stability, features, and maturity of Ext JS was extracted and amalgamated with the component-driven, fast, and light React ecosystem.
- In terms of features, all the advanced features are available in GRUI today like Tree Grid with Grouping, Sorting, and Filtering, Multi-Column Filters, Row and Column Virtualization, Advanced FilterBars, etc.
- Fully compatible with React 16-18.
- Works under both Class and Functional Components.
- TypeScripted.